# In SIP protocol, how do i share a secret for the Authentication challenge?

Tags: sip

I'm trying to establish a SIP 407 proxy authentication procedure. how does the shared secret mechanism works? how do i share a secret with the caller?

Comment: It seems you are implementing server side? It's not clear from your question. Please edit and make it clear.

Comment: The authentication mechanism for SIP is discussed in RFC3261 chapter 22 (Usage of HTTP Authentication). Usually Digest authentication is used, as described in RFC2617 (HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

SIP use the same mechanism as HTTP which is described in [rfc2617: HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)

The shared secret is the password -obviously-!

However, when the account is created, the database may contain only the HA1 value in order to hide the clear text password.

You will find everything on A1 and HA1 in Section 3.2.2.2 A1 of rfc2617.

```
 A1       = unq(username-value) ":" unq(realm-value) ":" passwd
```

An example would be:

```
A1        = yourlogin:sip.yourservice.com:Your Password
```

The H(A1) would be calculated on client side and used to produce the result. The result would also be calculdate from the server side with the H(A1) known entry. If they match, server can validate that user used the correct login and password.

H(A1) is usually the MD5 hash of the A1 value.

rfc2617 contains everything you need, as well as source code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This i know. my question is in case i'm a client from another domain and wishes to make a call to the callee in a different domain. i don't know the PWD or anything. how can the challenge be performed?

Comment: If you don't have the login/password, you can't authenticate. Obviously....